# Add class on scroll issue

Tags: jquery

I've added an add class function on scroll which I have used in other projects but it is not working this time round and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have the element I'm adding the class to set to `opacity: 0` and am adding a class with `opacity: 1` once the user has scrolled a number of pixels

HTML

```
<nav id="icons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">learn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#icons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 700; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if( scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx ) {
        $('#icons').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('#icons').removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be related to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Essentially, the `.show` properties don't override the `#icons` properties because IDs have higher specificity than classes.

I've added the ID to the `show` selector.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTopPx = 700; // distance to trigger
  var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx) {
    $('#icons').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('#icons').removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: calc(100vh + 1000px);
}

#icons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

#icons.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="icons">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">learn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Alternatively, you could remove a class instead of adding so that you don't need to override any properties.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTopPx = 700; // distance to trigger
  var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx) {
    $('#icons').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#icons').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: calc(100vh + 1000px);
}

#icons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  z-index: 20;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="icons" class="hide">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">learn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: In this case I would suggest using classes and modifiers, instead of id.

Comment: Your suggestion of changing the element's id to a class has done the job. Schoolboy error on my part. Many thanks